# Backup data from android device (Xiaomi mi A2)

Tags: backup, data-recovery, adb

I need to backup data from my android phone. OS is broken (unknown reason). see attached sreenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/znSXR.jpg
I can't enter bootloader - device stucks.
That's the only options I have https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uB0o.jpg
Device is not rooted. I'm PHP developer but have no android skills. I already tried **adb**, but unsuccessfully:

1. **adb backup** says "*adb: unable to connect for backup: closed*"
2. **adb shell** says "*error: closed*"
3. **adb pull** says "*adb: error: connect failed: closed*"

I can put ROM update via "**adb sideload**" but it says "u*pdate package is older than current build*", as I have newest Xiaomi update
I do not want to make hard reset before making a full data backup.

thanks for any help

Comment: If your bootloader is previously unlocked, in recovery the entry 'reboot to bootloader' should bring you fastboot mode, there you can try to flash TWRP

Comment: Unfortunately there is no known method for flashing TWRP with locked bootloader for your device. However, some hackers have investigated exploits via EDL Mode Qualcomm HSUSB QLoader 9008 (which you can trigger via test point) if your data is worth it, you can find someone who may break in. here is the theory http://forum.xda-developers.com/xiaomi-redmi-5a/how-to/bypass-bootloader-lock-redmi-5ariva-t3772381 and here is a method where the exploit is used http://xiaomitips.com/guide/how-to-root-locked-redmi-note-3-snapdragon.

Comment: beware even if managed to flash TWRP, you must find the right TWRP version which is able to decrypt your userdata partition. official latest is not always the best! for example Redmi 5 TWRP v3.3.1-0 has broken decryption, but there is a inofficial TWRP v3.2.3-0 which will successful decrypt (with default_password out of the box)

Comment: Thank you, this comment gives me to know  that is too difficult for me :) also there are many risks and the threat to waste a time. I already did a factory reset and that helped. all apps has been restored from google cloud. I just lost all the photos, but it is not a problem. thanks again for your time